# UINavigationController push method load next VCs elements before animation completes

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, transition

I have experienced a strange thing when I use `UINavigationController` with `push` method. Let's say we have a `ViewController` with two buttons *(sign in & sign up)*. When user taps each of the buttons, the app presents the proper `ViewController`, but the UI elements, placed on that `ViewController` (for example `UITextFields`, `Buttons`) appearing first, while the transition animation still taking place. 
I use a function to setup my layout in each `ViewController` and I'm not dealing with `Storyboard`.
I tried to use `viewWillLayoutSubviews()`, `viewWillAppear()`, etc, but experienced the same thing...

How can I reach smooth transition between the views?

Comment: You'll need to show the code you're using to get help. See [ask]

Comment: Show your code how you are maintaining the transitions and designing?

Comment: I'm going to provide code soon...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it. The overlapping Viewcontroller did not have background color defined.